# When I hot reload while debugging a flutter app with an android emulator, an error is displayed and the screen goes black

Tags: android, flutter, dart

error:

`E/Surface ( 6685): freeAllBuffers: 1 buffers were freed while being dequeued!`

`I/m.example.___( 6685): Background young concurrent copying GC freed 626248(23MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 15% free, 132MB/156MB, paused 2.375ms,119us total 102.357ms`

`E/Surface ( 6685): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb400007d4a67c3e0`

I have no knowledge of Flutter or Android, and I can't solve this error and the black screen phenomenon.
Please let me know if you have any advice or what could be the reason for this phenomenon.

Also, when this phenomenon occurs, some values that were saved locally using the Hive package are lost.

If you do a hot reload in the same way with flutter run instead of debugging, the contents of the output error will be different, so I will add it.

```
E/Surface (31761): freeAllBuffers: 1 buffers were freed while being dequeued!
E/Surface (31761): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb400007d4a601680
W/Firestore(31761): (24.6.0) [WatchStream]: (e884c0e) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=null, cause=java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host unreachable
W/Firestore(31761):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:183)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:570)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:450)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:250)
W/Firestore(31761):     at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:285)
W/Firestore(31761):     at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$3.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:535)
W/Firestore(31761):     at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
W/Firestore(31761): }.
W/Firestore(31761): (24.6.0) [WatchStream]: (e884c0e) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=null, cause=java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host unreachable
W/Firestore(31761):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:183)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:570)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:450)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:250)
W/Firestore(31761):     at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:285)
W/Firestore(31761):     at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$3.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:535)
W/Firestore(31761):     at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
W/Firestore(31761): }.
W/Firestore(31761): (24.6.0) [WatchStream]: (e884c0e) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=null, cause=java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host unreachable
W/Firestore(31761):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:183)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:570)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:450)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:250)
W/Firestore(31761):     at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:285)
W/Firestore(31761):     at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$3.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:535)
W/Firestore(31761):     at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
W/Firestore(31761): }.
W/Firestore(31761): (24.6.0) [WatchStream]: (e884c0e) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=null, cause=java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host unreachable
W/Firestore(31761):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:183)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:570)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:450)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:250)
W/Firestore(31761):     at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:285)
W/Firestore(31761):     at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$3.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:535)
W/Firestore(31761):     at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
W/Firestore(31761): }.
W/Firestore(31761): (24.6.0) [WatchStream]: (e884c0e) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=null, cause=java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host unreachable
W/Firestore(31761):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:183)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:570)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:450)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:250)
W/Firestore(31761):     at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:285)
W/Firestore(31761):     at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$3.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:535)
W/Firestore(31761):     at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/Firestore(31761):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
W/Firestore(31761): }.
```

Comment: Please try to improve your question for better understanding.